# How do I find the number of different possible matrices?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

Link to the actual problem : - https://www.codechef.com/problems/TREASURE

You are given a grid with N rows (numbered 1 through N) and M columns (numbered 1 through M).
Let's denote the cell in row 'r' and column 'c'  by  (r,c). Two cells of the grid are adjacent if they share a side.

Some of the cells of this grid contain treasures. You do not know exactly which cells contain them, but an analysis of the grid, called a treasure hunt map, is available. For each cell (i,j), you are given an integer A(i,j)  with the following meaning:

A(i,j)=−1: no information

A(i,j)=0: there is an even number of cells containing a treasure which are adjacent to the cell (i,j) .

A(i,j)=1: there is an odd number of cells containing a treasure which are adjacent to the cell (i,j) .

(Note:-Zero is considered as an even number)

A treasure layout is the set of all cells containing treasures. Find the number of possible treasure layouts that are consistent with all the given information.

Example:-

The following (3 X 2) matrix :-

1 -1

1 -1

1 0

Answer : - The count of possible matrices is '4'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts that might help towards building a complete solution. Looking at the example,

```
1 -1
1 -1
1  0

y -1
1  x
x  0
```

The zero implies the two `x`s are an even instance of treasures, which either way fix `y` with a treasure to satisfy the three cells adjacent to the middle-left 1:

```
T -1  or  T -1
1  -      1  T
-  0      T  0
```

The only other two cells that have an effect are the top and bottom left `1`s. Fixing one, implies the other:

```
1  x  or  1  T
T  x      x  x
1  x      1  T
```

2 * 2 = 4

In general, a restriction arises when two directly diagonal cells or two in-line cells separated by a third are not -1. We can also notice that there are essentially two independent matrices. `x`s' values imply treasure arrangements only in the `o`s and vice versa:

```
x o x o x
o x o x o
x o x o x
```